# Plesk: View system resources (e.g., RAM, CPU, etc...) for a VPS

Tags: server, performance, vps, plesk, management

I've setup my first VPS. Previously I've always been hosting my projects on a shared hosting account. I run a couple of little personal projects on the VPS, including one that is continuously scraping data from the web.

I'd like to know how I'm using the resources / how much RAM/CPU I have free.

I manage the server with Plesk version 11. Is there a simple way I can see a break down of the resources? If not, is there a plugin / script I can install?

Something similar to Activity Monitor (on Mac) would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you don't need a plugin. Just log into Plesk and go to:

`Server Management -> Tools & Settings -> Server Information` *(under the "Server Management" column)*

It breaks down the following:

- CPU Usage
- Physical Memory Usuage
- Virtual Memory Usage
- Hard Disk Usage

You might also find "Server Health" helpful too, because it breaks down a lot of the above even further, including Plesk application processes by percentage (e.g., Apache, MySQL, etc...). To view that, just go to:

`Server Management -> Health Monitoring`

If you want an even further breakdown of the processes running, you can access `top` (on Linux) via the SSH control panel applet, available in each domain account (unless it was restricted).

For Windows servers, you can use Remote Desktop (providing it's enabled), and then connect remotely to run Task Manager (just like on a Windows desktop).